# Play song from Google Music in app

Tags: android, android-music-player, google-music

I have been developing an app that allows users to do certain activities to gain points, one of which is tracking exercise. I have a media player that plays content from the device, that was easy enough, but most people use cloud based storage like Google Music. It seems counter intuitive to only allow people to play music that is stored directly on their devices. So I started searching the web. I found ways to list playlists and from there I am able to list all songs, artists, genres, playlists, etc from Google Music using ContentResolver and querying the various end points from "content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/..." Now that I have all that information I am trying to find a way to let the user actually select a song and play it. The setup is simple enough, just a content resolver that queries the MusicContent database then shows the user artwork, artist, song, whatever the case may be. Is there any way to actually play the content that can be found from the content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/album or /artist or /audio or...? I am more than happy to post up the code I have that gets all of the information from the database if that would help, I just wasn't sure if it was needed for this question.

A bonus question... If it is not possible to do on and Android device, does anyone have any idea how to go about contacting Google to try to partner up and allow my app to play content from Google Music? I have been to their developer pages, not one single mention that Google Music even exists. I have projects on firebase, not that helpful here. I have tried using the support option in Google Music but they are only there to help with "Paid Content". It seriously seems like outside the Paid Content support Google Music doesn't exist to Google what so ever. Please, any information would be appreciated. I have been scouring the internet for hours with absolutely nothing to show for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/androidpublisher/v3) that you can include in your Android project.

I'm pretty sure you will need a paid google play developer's account to playback these files but that's the whole premise of it, isn't it?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/dev-guide) is the starting point for setting up the OAuth tokens for letting a user login.

They also provide easy to use classes for [Media Uploading](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-upload) or [Media Downloading](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download) -> what you will need to do in the background for file playback I presume.

*I'm 99 percent sure this is what you are looking for, but please comment if otherwise!*